# Angular2 Error as :GetStateById/%221%22 of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: json, angular2-services

When i assign value to url as

```
 onselect(id: number) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(id)
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }); 
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        var GetstateValue = this.http.get("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById" + '/' + data, options)
       GetstateValue.subscribe((res => this.Success(res)), res => this.Error(res));
    }
```

Throughing Error as Internal Server Error as :34339/Home/GetStateById/%221%22  When i click on that url its Giving Me as `http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/"1"` How can i Remove ""  from My Url

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use back ticks

```
var GetstateValue = this.http.get(`http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/${id}`, options)
```

[Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Hope this helps